# Action Script 2, I want to stop the counting down to 0

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, desktop-application

I need help with Action Script 2.0

I have this scoreboard system with 2 buttons one to count up to a certain number and the other to count down if i need to.
However, the problem with the count down button.

Count Down button code:

```
on(release) {
score.text = 0; 
score.text = scorebk
_root.scorebk--;
```

if the score is 9 for example when i count down it adds up 1 and then it counts down normally, also when score is 0 it goes to -1...etc.
I do not want that. how can i stop this button from going to minus? and counts normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check that the value is greater than zero before you decrement:

```
on(release) {   
    if(scorebk > 0){
       scorebk--;  
    }
    score.text = scorebk; 
}
```